# How to change default GUI environment in SUSE Linux?

Tags: linux

How to change default (for example change form KDE to GNOME or other) GUI environment in SUSE Linux? What environments is available for SUSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Yast you can pretty much install any GUI out there (kde,gnome and most of the lesser know ones)

If more then one GUI is installed you should be able to just select the gui of your choice at the logging screen using the Session dropdown.